# firestore loadBundle continues to store deleted documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a bundle of **3** documents. Then I deleted **2** of them and created the bundle again. So the bundle now contains **one** document! And the application cache contains **3**

Then I download the bundle again:

```
const resp = await fetch(downloadUrl);
await loadBundle(db, resp.body); //{totalDocuments: 1} - as expected
const query = await namedQuery(db, `my-bundle-query`);
if (query) {
   const snap = await getDocsFromCache(query); //Nope! there should be one document, but there are three
}
```

Looks like a bug. I think loadBundle should somehow keep track of deleted documents. What should I do?

UPDATE:

namedQuery - query the entire cache. But the expected behavior is to get only the documents associated with the bundle. So this doesn't work at all - in my namedQuery I have a limit of 4 documents but got more from the cache!!

So the [official example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles) is wrong because it faces the same problem I described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL:DR;

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the way that bundles are currently coded. It would also be out of scope for bundles as they are designed to be used against collections with large amounts of reused data for the initial load of a page.

If you think that `loadBundle` should purge items from the local cache that aren't returned in the bundle, you should [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add this feature to the `loadBundle` call (e.g. `loadBundle(rawBundle, /* forceRefresh = */ true)`) or [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

---

#### The Details

For example's sake, lets assume your query is "Get the first 10 posts in collection /Posts".

Upon requesting the bundle for this query, the first bundle returns the following results:

```json
{
  "/Posts/D9p7MbcYCbTNzcXLrzfQ": { /* post data */ },
  "/Posts/xz3eY1Gwsjl4tTxTjXyR": { /* post data */ },
  "/Posts/fIvk5LF2zj2xgpgWIv9h": { /* post data */ }
}
```

which you then load using `loadBundle`.

Next, you delete two of these documents from the server using another client (using the same client would delete them from the local cache).

Now you re-request the bundle, which returns:

```json
{
  "/Posts/fIvk5LF2zj2xgpgWIv9h": { /* post data */ }
}
```

Upon calling `loadBundle`, the library iterates through the collection of documents in the bundle, updating the local cache for each document:

```
// this is psuedo-code, not the true implementation
function loadBundle(rawBundle) {
  decodedBundle = parseBundle(rawBundle);

  decodedBundle.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    cachedDocuments.set(doc.id, doc);
  })

  return { // return bundle load progress
    totalDocuments: decodedBundle.docs.length,
    /* ... other stats ... */
  };
}
```

In the above psuedo-code, you can see that only the documents that are included in the bundle are updated in the local cache. Documents not included in the bundle are not updated and the stats returned are related to the documents included in the bundle that was just decoded - not the results of the relevant query.

When you run the named query, the query is decoded, compared and executed against the local cache. As the former documents currently match the query according to the cache, they are included in the results.

The documents in the local cache will only be omitted when:

- The decoded query returns more than 10 results, and they don't meet the criteria of the query.
- The query is executed against the live database.
- If the downloaded bundle included metadata indicating that the documents were deleted.

So for the local cache to be purged, the bundle would have to contain:

```json
{
  "/Posts/D9p7MbcYCbTNzcXLrzfQ": _DELETED,
  "/Posts/xz3eY1Gwsjl4tTxTjXyR": _DELETED,
  // ... for every deleted document that ever existed ...
  "/Posts/fIvk5LF2zj2xgpgWIv9h": { /* post data */ }
}
```

Returning such a bundle would be technically complex and incredibly inefficient.

When requesting the bundle, you *could* include a list of document IDs, where if a given document ID doesn't exist, a document deletion is included in the bundle's data. However, in doing so, you may as well just make a normal database request to the server using `getDocs` or `onSnapshot` for the same result which would be faster and cheaper.

Bundles are designed to be used against collections with large amounts of reused data and generally only on the initial load of a page. If a post is deleted in the top 50 results, you would invalidate the cached results and rebuild the bundle. All new users would see the changed results immediately and only those users with the local copy would see them.

If you think that `loadBundle` should purge items from the local cache that aren't returned in the bundle, you should [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add this feature to the `loadBundle` call (e.g. `loadBundle(rawBundle, /* forceRefresh = */ true)`).

Comment: So the official example is a lie https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles Because in their example, if you delete the document, it will remain in the cache. It also breaks the logic of named query, because they are not related to the documents in the bundle, but are simply executed over the cache. Therefore, all the promises that instead of reading 50 documents you can create a bundle from them and read them once are lies, because you have to read same 50 documents to keep track of document deletions - this is a failure on a planetary scale. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ValeraKvip if you have 50 docs in the bundle, but two have recently been deleted, you only get hit for 2 reads after loading them into the cache using `getDocsFromCache` and then getting the latest version using `getDocs`/`onSnapshot`. That's still a saving of 48 reads per user.

Comment: why? How do I know which documents have been deleted without querying for them all? I agree with you that the bundle should not know anything about its previous versions and delete the document. But the fact that namedQuery does not belong to the bundle (reads all the documents in the cache) or some other method that would read only the documents in the bundle is a problem.

Comment: @ValeraKvip When you attach a listener to a Firestore location, the SDK is told the names of documents that satisfy the query by the server. The SDK then compares its cached documents against the names and asks the server for any documents it doesn't have the data for already. Each new document incurs a read when you download its contents while asking the index for results does not.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to prove this behavior? Also, the deleted document will cost one read for EACH client! Like every changed will cost a read for EVERY client- and I just wanted to escape from that with bundles

Comment: @ValeraKvip Here is the source of the [`loadBundle` API method](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/171b78b762826a640d267dd4dd172ad9459c4561/packages/firestore/src/api/database.ts#L573-L598) and its [implementation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/171b78b762826a640d267dd4dd172ad9459c4561/packages/firestore/src/core/sync_engine_impl.ts#L1595-L1650), along with the [cached results update logic](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/171b78b762826a640d267dd4dd172ad9459c4561/packages/firestore/src/core/view.ts#L108-L250).

Comment: @ValeraKvip If you instead meant links to prove the behaviour of read/write billing, the [billing documentation on listening to queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) covers this.

Comment: I didn't ask this question quite correctly, I asked another - more correct one. But you have given a great well described answer, Thanks. I accept as an answer.