# firestore bundle process deletes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The official bundle [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles) looks very good. But I'm wondering how you handle deleting documents?
 Because namedQuery (as I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75357964/firestore-loadbundle-continues-to-store-deleted-documents)) is not related to bundle files, but runs over the entire cache.

So, the first time you open the app, you've downloaded a bundle of 100 documents and placed them in the cache
Then you deleted 1 document and generated a new bundle of 99 documents
Reopen the app- you have downloaded a bundle of 99 documents, but the removed one remains in the cache.

How are you going to remove it? Listen for them? So you just devalued the reason to use the bundle!

Any ideas?

Comment: I face the same problem, I planned and worked for 3 months to fetch data using the firestore bundle & firebase hosting CDN and now I am surprised by this problem. Also, this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193461/how-to-make-firestore-query-cache-shared-between-clients-using-firestore-data-bu

Comment: @user3121348, So I had a long correspondence with firebase support, and they said that there is such a problem (although they don't consider it a problem).
For my project, I abandoned bundles and started generating pages with ssr. I've tried all the options and there are no good solutions. Perhaps the best one would be to load the bundle the first time you open the app, and then after a while (or when a new version of the bundle is released) delete the cached bundle and load a new one.