# how to make firestore query cache shared between clients using Firestore Data Bundles & CDN

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to cache some firestore queries between users to [serve docs from a CDN via Bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles).

so I have created the following cloud function:

```
exports.getStoreCategoriesBundle = functions.region(DEFAULT_REGION).https.onRequest(async (request: any, response: any) => {

    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    if (!request || !request.query || !request.query.storeId) {
        // end function with 401 header
        response.set("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0").status(401).end("Query data required.");
        return;
    }

    // Query all categories
    const allStoreCategories = await firestore.collection(`stores/${request.query.storeId}/store_categories`)
        .where("status", "==", 1)
        .orderBy("count", "desc")
        .limit(500)
        .get();

    // Build the bundle from the query results
    const bundleBuffer = firestore.bundle("all-store-categories-"+request.query.storeId)
    .add("all-store-categories-query-"+request.query.storeId, allStoreCategories)
    .build();

    // Cache the response for up to 120 minutes (7200 / 60 = 120 minutes);
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=7200, s-maxage=14400");

    response.end(bundleBuffer);
});
```

Then I load a bundle on the client side:

```
async fetchFromBundle(bundleName: string, queryName: string) {
    // Fetch the bundle from Firebase Hosting, if the CDN cache is hit the 'X-Cache'
    // response header will be set to 'HIT'
    const resp = await fetch(bundleName);

    // Load the bundle contents into the Firestore SDK
    const task = await loadBundle(this.firestore, resp.body);
    console.log("task: " , task);

    // Query the results from the cache
    // Note: omitting "source: cache" will query the Firestore backend.
    const query = await namedQuery(this.firestore, queryName);
    const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromCache(query);

    // Use the results
    
    let docs : DocumentData[] = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      docs.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id
        // metadata: doc.metadata,
        // ref: doc.ref,
      });
    });
    return docs;
}
```

The code works successfully, but I noticed that the function is executed in the cloud for each client separately. and when the function is executed that means query documents from Cloud Firestore.

**For example:**

When I call "fetchFromBundle" on my phone device the cloud function is executed on Google Cloud Console.

Then if I called "fetchFromBundle" again with the same parameters used above but from a different device (like my desktop) The cloud function is executed also before the cache period is expired that was generated by the first client (my phone device).

What I want to do is to make the bundle cache shared between clients from Firebase Hosting CDN. So the first client must query and build the bundle and all other clients who come after that must load the bundle from the CDN cache without any query until the CDN cache expires.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, as u can see "Estimated Savings" at the end of the Firebase documentation page but in my case I think something is wrong or missed in my code as long as the function is executed for every new client and not using CDN caching for all clients.